# Trying to SerializeObject and getting c# list json error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on the following JSON data and when trying to serialize an object I get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here are my classes:

```
    public class Hotel
    {
        [JsonProperty("Hotel")]
        public Address1 Address1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address1
    {
        public string GuestData { get; set; }
        public string GuestName { get; set; }
        public string GuestSurName { get; set; }
    }
```

And I tried to serialize this way:

```
List<Hotel> Hotel = new List<Hotel>();
Hotel e = new Hotel();
e.Address1.GuestName = "Kevin";
e.Address1.GuestSurName = "Jones";
Hotel.Add(e);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Hotel, Formatting.Indented);
textBox1.Text = json;
```

I put the code in `Form_Load` and I get the error

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning memory to `Address1` class property inside your `Hotel` class. So that's why you are getting exception at line `e.Address1.GuestName = "Kevin";`

Try below default constructor to assign memory to `Address1` class property.

```
public class Hotel
{
    public Hotel()
    {
        Address1 = new Address1();
    }

    [JsonProperty("Hotel")]
    public Address1 Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do it however it seems I was applying the wrong solution. Now I see what was my error. Thank you er-shoaib. Solved!

Comment: glad to hear. if my answer solved your problem then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)